# How to enter RN4678 module in command mode?

Tags: bluetooth, module

How to enter RN4678 module in command mode?

Does anyone know about connecting the module and the procedure for entering command mode?

Connection:

- P2_0   LOW
- P2_4   HIGH
- EAN    LOW
- SW_BTN HIGH
- P3_3   Pulled Low
- P3_2   Pulled Low
- CTS    Pulled High
- RTS    Pulled Down

---

I am communicate with module through serial Terminal(Docklight). But I am getting garbage value
does not enter in command mode

Do you know about connection ?

---

[image]

I have uploaded screen shoot of serial terminal output. What is the meaning of that output and solution for this?

Comment: yogesh shekade - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional info, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or comment to respond to a minor point. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: *"I have uploaded screen shoot of serial terminal output. What is the meaning of that output and solution for this?"* You're using your tool incorrectly (I can observe at least 2 errors). Maybe you'd like to re-read my answer.

Comment: Docklight is also serial terminal . Which software is suitable for communication with module..?

Comment: Please don't change your original question once it has been solved (I did a rollback). Ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> How to enter RN4678 module in command mode?
>
> Does anyone know about connecting the module and the procedure for entering command mode?

In order to communicate with the RN4678, you initially have to use hardware flow control (CTS and RTS). This can be changed later on (which I'll usually do).

By default, to enter *Command Mode* you have to send the sequence **`$$$`**. To exit command mode you'll have to send **`---`**. Also, all commands need to be terminated with a *Carriage Return* character (`\r`, 0x0D).

---

> I am communicate with module through serial Terminal(Docklight). But I am getting garbage value does not enter in command mode
>
> Do you know about connection ?

The out-of-the-box communication settings are:

- baud rate: 115200 bps
- 8 data bits
- no parity
- 1 stop bit
- hardware flow control enabled

I don't know *Docklight* so I don't know if it can handle hardware handshaking. I like to use [HTerm](https://www.der-hammer.info/pages/terminal.html) when I want to fiddle with the serial port.

Btw, I'm not affiliated to *HTerm*.

---

Your hardware setup is configured for the operational mode *'Write EEPROM and Test Mode'*. I don't know the implications of that mode, as I haven't used it. *'Write FLASH'* is used for firmware updates. Other than that I've always only used *'Normal Operation/Application mode'*.

[image]

<sub>Source: [RN4678 Datasheet](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/RN4678#document-table)</sub>

---

*Some more info about my configuration procedure.*

**IMPORTANT: Don't just blindly execute these commands! You have to understand what it does, and you should ensure that this is feasible for your hardware configuration.**

After the initial communication is established, I'll usually assign *Command/Data Switch* to pin P3_7. This is done with command `SX,07,0B`.

[image]

[image]

Then you have to enable *Fast Mode*, by issuing the command `SQ,C000`.

[image]

<sup>Source: [RN4678 Datasheet](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/RN4678#document-table)</sup>

A full startup configuration sequence could look as follows:

[image]
[image]